# Images are not properly aligning in responsive design

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, blogger, responsive-images

I have developed a responsive website design. Here it is [secondgf](http://www.secondgf.com/) . In one of my post I have arranged all the images at center. It is working properly on desktop and all images seems properly aligned at center, but when I open it on a mobile device all the images get aligned at right. [image] My previously written post also have images aligned at center and it works perfect in both mobile and desktop. This is the working post-[secondgf.com](http://www.secondgf.com/2016/03/top-10-reasons-to-root-your-android.html)  I tried to figure out what is wrong with the post but no luck. It is hosted on blogger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not the image, is the elment that contains, in this example the element "a". This has margins of 1em inline, remove them and the image will not move ;)

[image]

Comment: You are right. It worked after I removed 'a', but now it is showing the code from the HTML in post. Check [secondgf](http://www.responsinator.com/?url=www.secondgf.com%2F)

Comment: you should not delete the "a" you have to delete this: style="margin-left: 1em; margin-right: 1em;"

Comment: You was right. Thanx. Do you have any idea why **style="margin-left: 1em; margin-right** this appearing?? Is it by default or something wrong in my template design???